# What do the color changes on the Chrome tools button mean?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, the tools button ('customize and control') used to have an icon of a wrench; now it has three horizontal lines, which is fine; but the horizontal lines change color between green, orange and red. What do the color changes mean?

Comment: When do you see them change colour? I have never noticed this.

Comment: @moobot I've never caught them in the act of changing color but they are different colors depending on which webpage I'm looking at, e.g. they are orange right now.

Comment: doesn't that indicate the sync status of your google account ?

Comment: The Google Chrome tools button, the button formerly known as the wrench icon, now seems to be called the hotdog icon rather than the wrench icon.  I was searching for "why is google chrome hotdog icon red" in order to try to find out what was going on with the color changes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just found [Update Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414?hl=en-GB) in the Google help docs.

> #### When are updates available
>
> Normally updates happen in the background when you close and re-open your browser. However, if you haven't closed your browser in a while you might see the Chrome menu on the browser change colour to green, orange, or red. If you see green that means an update has been available for 2 days, orange – 4 days and red – 7 or more days. To apply and available update, just follow the steps below.
>
> 1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
> 2. Select **Update Google Chrome**.
> 3. In the confirmation dialogue that appears, click **Restart**. The browser saves your opened tabs and windows and reopens them automatically when it restarts. If you'd prefer not to restart right away, click **Not now**. The next time you restart your browser, the update will automatically be applied.

In case the update does not change the Color od chrome menu button, do sign out and sign in again, and then the color would change back to BLACK, indicating that this is the most recent version!